# remove regionals from decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion

we got regional related web client, where currency is set as in regional format, which we parse like:

```
bool result = decimal.TryParse(currencyValue, NumberStyles.Currency, myCulture, out value);
```

when we serialize this decimal to xml and decimal was previously parsed in myCulture=en-US, xmlserializer returns `<Curr id="2" amnt="100000000.00"/>` and deserialize it back to same number... but when we do it in sk-SK or cs-CZ it returns `<Curr id="2" amnt="100000000,00"/>` which returns *100 on deserialization (ignores comma)...

is there possibility to remove this regional from decimal, or make it invariant?
(if I don't want to convert it to string and parse back again to handle regionals)

Comment: Serialize using the same culture everywhere (`InvariantCulture` looks like a good fit).

Comment: If I understood right - I find it difficult to believe.  Are you sure you're not using XmlSerializer to serialize a string rather than a decimal?  Or are you using custom serialization?  Post code that illustrates what's happening.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it is a decimal and yes, is unbelievable to me too... there is a decimal? object, which shows value 100 on debugging, but writes 100.00 in xml if it was parsed with en-EN locale and 100,00 if it was cs-CZ... now I'm not able to show more code, from home I have no access to tfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I write answer to my own question, to can close this theme...

there was a new interesting point, what I get today morning after begin working. Problematic decimal was added to the distionary before serializing, which is a little bit problem, because IDictionary can;t be serialized, until it implement IXmlSerializable. There are two methods to override, ReadXml and WriteXml. And here is the goal, in WriteXml there was used `decimalValue.ToString()`, which makes the problem. I dont know why it is, but this `.ToString()` returns the missmatch results what I describe in question. I dont know, how it happens, because in testing project it works perfect, but in our full context don't. But as agent Mulder believed, [the truth is out there](http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/3088/decimal.png)

So only what I need to do, was `decimalValue.ToString()` changing to `decimalValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Regional is for on-screen display--you display information to the user in the format that they understand or like.  When data isn't being displayed to the user (in memory, in database, over-the-wire) always serialize it in a known format.  In terms of culture info, this is generally InvariantCulture, as @Oded noted.

This allows you to transfer data from one culture to another without having each culture know about the other.

Comment: we are using standard .net (de)serialization with invariant culture (I'm not sure now, if there is one defined)... our problem is, that only place, where we using regional settings is in parsing incoming data and showing it on page... user insert amount to the textbox, then we parse it with selected regional settings (I got two users, one with en-EN, second cs-CZ)... result from this is a decimal? (nullable), which goes around all process (with no other regional checking or processing)... this decimal? is at the end serialized into xml as I write in my question.

Comment: User enters data -> program parses data with users regional settings -> parse data is stored with invariant culture.  When showing data -> data is retreived with invariant culture -> data is formatter in user's culture (en-EN or cs-CZ) -> data is displayed for user.